# Query State Category

Tags: azure-devops

I'm not able to get a query to work that will find all of my Work Item Types that are not in the 'Completed' state category.

```
Assigned To = @Me
AND
State:Not In Group:Completed
```

I expected that the query would only show me Work Items that have a state from a state category that is not, 'Completed.' In other words to show me all 'Work Items' that are assigned to me and still need to be worked on.

Answer (score 1):

Moments after I posted the question, I was able to figure it out.  It appears that it matters in which order you enter your clauses.  You have to first add a clause to find the state, then the assignee.  So I just reversed the order and it worked:

State: Not In Group: Completed AND Assigned To = @Me

Comment: This is incorrect. You are misinterpeting "Completed" as a State Category, but it's not; it's just a State.  You're only filtering out the Completed state, not the Closed state.